# Dividing the image into equal number of parts in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have lena image in Matlab. First I need to find the centroid **C**, and then divide the image into equal number of parts. I can calculate the centroid of the image but from that how can I divide the image into equal number of parts as shown below. Please anyone help me.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: How do you want the sections that include white space to be handled? As white?

Comment: also how do you want the final image to be oriented? eg. if you cut it into 16 parts and there are no horizontal/vertical cuts

Comment: the white part at the top/bottom and left/right will be replaced by zero values. Actually First I want to divide the image as shown above. then I want to calculate the pixel under each line

Comment: do you only need the pixel under each line? that sounds like a different question/approach altogether

Comment: Yes at the last step.. But I just want to draw like this.

Comment: if you only want the pixel values but don't need the partition image within it, just skip the partition step and use logical indexing to get the values under the pixels. I didn't understand your response, do you need the partitioned image or not?

Comment: How can I get pixel values under the line without partition the image?

Comment: That should make it easier to do. That relates to the next question I was going to ask you. How do you define the line? It can have zero width and not overlap anything or it could be 500 px wide and overlap everything. From your drawing, you have obviously used a fixed pixel width. Using a set of constraints and logical statements, it shouldn't be too hard to create a logical index to get the pixel values under the line.

Comment: In that case, I will have 8 lines and the number of pixels under each line is not fix it may have zero values pixels or anything. I am not worried about the size of pixels under each line.

Comment: Can you please help in the code how can you use set of constraints and logical statements to find that pixels?

Comment: Edited my answer for all angle lines, also edited the link to the function, BTW, you don't have to unaccept the answer each time if you need more help.. you could just ask :)

Answer (score 4):

Using [`poly2mask`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/poly2mask.html) to create binary sectors and using the resulting sectors for `indexing`

## Code:

```
im = imread('peppers.png');
r = 300;
out1 = ones(max(size(im,1),r*2)+2,max(size(im,2),r*2)+2,3).*255;

xoffset = floor((size(out1,2)-size(im,2))/2);
yoffset = floor((size(out1,1)-size(im,1))/2);

out1(yoffset:yoffset+size(im,1)-1,xoffset:xoffset+size(im,2)-1,:) = im(:,:,:);
im = out1;

cy = floor(size(im,1)/2);
cx = floor(size(im,2)/2);

figure;
imshow(uint8(im));
hold on
pos = [cx-r+1 cy-r+1 r*2 r*2];
rectangle('Position',pos,'Curvature',[1 1]);
x1 = [-r, 0, -r*cosd(45), -r*cosd(45); r, 0, r*cosd(45), r*cosd(45)]+cx+1;
y1 = [0, -r, -r*sind(45), r*sind(45); 0, r, r*sind(45), -r*sind(45)]+cy+1;
plot(x1,y1);
hold off

figure;
for i = 0:45:315
    t = linspace(-i,-i-45,128);
    x = [cx, cx+r*cosd(t), cx];
    y = [cy, cy+r*sind(t), cy];
    bw = poly2mask( x, y, size(im,1),size(im,2));
    bw = repmat(bw,1,1,3);
    out = ones(size(im,1),size(im,2),size(im,3)).*155;
    out(bw) = im(bw);
    subplot(2,4,(i/45)+1); imshow(uint8(out));
end;
```

## Results:

**Original Image**

[image]

**Partitions drawn over Original Image**

[image]

**Segments of the image**

[image]

## Update

for getting pixel values of the lines, by using Bresenham function from [here](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28190-bresenham-optimized-for-matlab/content/bresenham.m)

```
figure;
bw1 = zeros(size(im,1),size(im,2));
outmat = zeros(size(bw1));
[X,Y] = bresenham(cx+1-r,cy+1,cx+1+r,cy+1);
ind = sub2ind(size(outmat), Y, X);
outmat(ind) = 1;
[X,Y] = bresenham(cx+1,cy+1-r,cx+1,cy+1+r);
ind = sub2ind(size(outmat), Y, X);
outmat(ind) = 1;
[X,Y] = bresenham(cx+1-r*cosd(45),cy+1-r*sind(45),cx+1+r*cosd(45),cy+1+r*sind(45));
ind = sub2ind(size(outmat), Y, X);
outmat(ind) = 1;
[X,Y] = bresenham(cx+1-r*cosd(45),cy+1+r*sind(45),cx+1+r*cosd(45),cy+1-r*sind(45));
ind = sub2ind(size(outmat), Y, X);
outmat(ind) = 1;
se = strel('disk',5);    %// change the '5' value to affect thickness of the line
outmat = imdilate(outmat,se);
outmat = repmat(boolean(outmat),1,1,3);
outmat1 = zeros(size(outmat));
outmat1(outmat) = im(outmat);
imshow(uint8(outmat1));
```

**Pixel values under each lines**

[image]

Comment: How can I calculate no of pixels under each colored line?

Comment: @FrqKhan 'under'? what do you mean by that? no. of pixels in each sector?

Comment: I mean I want to calculate all the pixels values lie along each line at 0,45,90 degree

Comment: How can I get values for different angle lines?

Comment: @FrqKhan Consider accepting the answer if you no longer need help for this problem

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I may have some questions from time to time.
I want to know that can we set the thickness of these lines?

Comment: @FrqKhan, Edited, with added comments. Check out.

Comment: I am getting error in running this full code 
Error using bresenham
Too many input arguments.

Comment: Update the function from the link provided.. i changed the link.

Answer (score 2):

Check the following code. I just did it for a grayscale image. You can now change it to a color image as well. Check and pls confirm this is what you wanted.

```
clear all;

i = rgb2gray(imread('hestain.png'));
imshow(i);

cr = floor(size(i,1)/2);
cl = floor(size(i,2)/2);

r = min(cr, cl);
a = 90;

r1 = cr;
c1 = size(i,2);
v1=[c1 r1]-[cl cr];

i2 = zeros(size(i,1),size(i,2),ceil(360/a));

for ri = 1:size(i,1)
    for ci = 1:size(i,2)
        v2=[ci ri]-[cl cr];
        a2 = mod(-atan2(v1(1)*v2(2)-v1(2)*v2(1), v1*v2'), 2*pi) * 180/pi;
        d2 = pdist([ci ri; cl cr],'euclidean');
        if d2<=r
            if ceil(a2/a)==0
                a2 =1;
            end
            i2(ri,ci,ceil(a2/a)) = i(ri,ci);
        end
    end
end

figure;
for i=1:360/a
    subplot(2,180/a,i);
    imshow(mat2gray(i2(:,:,i)));
end
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much showing the example code. I want to know that, how can I draw a lines to divide the image as showed in the above image?

Comment: As my ultimate goal is to calculate the number of pixels under the line, how can I do it from this?

Comment: I think now you can easily proceed with this code :-)

Comment: Hwathanie: can you please explain me how can I do that with this code?

Comment: One easier way may be, walk through each pixel in the image and find the angle that pixel creates with the center as in the above code. Then you can count the number of pixels lie along each line as you want.

Comment: what is v1 and v2, do I need to calculate this?

Comment: Hwathanie: Can you please edit the above code the way you suggested to count the pixels lie along each line. it will be very helpful for me